# Facebook like button avatars

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-like, avatar

I want to display more friend avatars on the like button box when I insert the code on my website, is it possible? I got the code from this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ At the moment, the box just shows 7 friend avatars at maximum.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on how many of your friends like the page.  Another option you can use is to display a like box with a [facepile box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/) next to it. eg:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="50" data-show-faces="false" style="float:left;></div>
<div class="fb-facepile" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/" data-size="large" data-max-rows="1" data-width="350"></div>
```